# Is there a method reference in JDK for subtracting doubles?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

`Double::sum` is a method reference for adding doubles, ie. `(a,b) -> a+b`.

Why is there not a method reference for minus in the JDK? I.e. `(a,b) -> a-b`?

Comment: Using a library for this is counter-productive, you already spent more time writing this question than the code you already know works and is simple enough.

Comment: https://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/function/Integers.html though not used myself

Comment: `Double::sum` is a handy method reference for reduction operations and similar. Since minus is not associative, it’s not appropriate for such operations. However, if you need a minus, just use `(a,b)->a-b`. Adding a 3rd library dependency for that sounds insane.

Comment: Ouch.  Some harsh criticisms of the question here!  In my case, I need to supply a ToDoubleBiFunction and I could see that Double::sum was available, but not Double::minus, and I wondered why.  Also, I personally find Double::sum more readable than (a,b) -> a+b (and Double::+ or just + would be even better) but that's perhaps personal style.

Comment: @Holger I'll mark your answer correct if you mention the difference between Double::sum and Double::minus.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The primary purpose of methods like `Double.sum` is to aid use cases like reduction or [`Arrays.parallelPrefix`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelPrefix-double:A-java.util.function.DoubleBinaryOperator-) Since minus is not an associative function, it is not appropriate for this use case.

Adding 3rd party library dependencies just for the sake of such a simple method, is not recommended. Keep in mind, that you always can create your own method, if you prefer named methods over lambda expressions.

E.g.

```
static double minus(double a, double b) {
    return a-b;
}
```

and using `MyClass::minus` is as informative as `ThirdPartyClass::minus`…

Answer (score 2):

There is no inbuilt method. But I don't think, itdo any other magic than simply doing

```
double result = a-b;
```

It seems you are over thinking here :)

Answer (score 0):

As such there is no inbuilt method which is used to subtract the doubles. However if you are using BigDecimal to store the decimals then you can try this:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("10.6");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("4.3");
BigDecimal result = a.subtract(b);
System.out.println(result);
```

else you can use the simple way of subtracting two numbers ie, a-b. Also to note that in Java, double values are [IEEE floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Answer (score -1):

Use java.math.BigDecimal

Link:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#subtract%28java.math.BigDecimal%29